# Encoding with variable frame rate in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Till now I was doing all of my encoding using fixed frame (programmatically) using ffmpeg. Now I need to support variable frame rate. I started with just commenting the portion of my code which was setting frame rate. 
However it is not working. My function is failing at avcodec_open2. Please someone suggest me how to go about supporting the variable frame rate. 
Also I came to know not all codec support variable frame rate. So which codecs are normally used when encoding with variable frame rate. Please suggest.

Thanks 
Pradeep

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am interested in this too. @praks411

Answer (score 8):

I realize the post is pretty old, however I hope being able to help some folks having the same problem (I just did)...

Use the [fps filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps-1) or the [framerate filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate). Being an ffpmeg n00b as well, there's no guarantee for 100% correctness, but at least this worked for me:

I created a filtergraph just like in the [filtering_video.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering__video_8c_source.html) example. For the `filters` argument of `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr`, I specified `fps=fps=30:round=near`, for example. Then I fed frames into the filtergraph whenever I got some, calculating the pts as

```
float fps = (float)( codecContext->time_base.num ) / codecContext->time_base.den;
this->frame->pts = (__int64)( ( timestamp - timestamp0 ) / fps );
```

where `timestamp` is the frame's time in seconds and `timestamp0` is the time of the very first frame being recorded. Both are floating point values and result from my custom built timer. When you're using a library providing timestamps for your captured frames (such as DirectShow), you should of course use those.